# How to construct quarter point element in finite element

Tags: finite-element-method

When calculating the stress intensity factor of a cracked body, singular elements are usually used to divide the region near the crack tip in order to meet the requirement of singularity at the crack tip. For the plane element, by folding one of the edges of the quadrilateral element and adjusting the position of the middle node of the quadrilateral element, the singular element satisfying different singularity requirements can be obtained.
The singularity of r-1/2 can be obtained at the crack tip by folding one of the elements of the second-order quadrilateral element, binding the three nodes of the folded edge together, and moving the intermediate node to the 1 / 4 position of the edge of the element.
How to generate quarter point singular element by program?

[image]

Comment: The question is unclear. Is it a question about _Mathematica_? Are you trying to implement this element in `NDSolve`?

Comment: Using elementmesh in mathematica12.2 can draw some finite element meshs

Comment: Is this for drawing purposes or for computing? ElementMesh["Wireframe"] will only ever draw linear elements (even if the mesh is second order)

Comment: in order to calculate the stress at the crack tip

Comment: @sgzslg do you have literature where such elements for crack tip are described ?

Comment: ON THE USE OF ISOPARAMETRIC FINITE ELEMENTS IN LINEAR FRACTURE MECHANICS

Answer (score 3):

This will not work for various reasons, one is that you can not collapse elements

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
m1 = ToElementMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> {{0.`, 0.`}, {1.`, 0.`}, {1.`, 1.`}, {0.`, 
     1.`}, {0.5`, 0.`}, {1.`, 0.5`}, {0.5`, 1.`}, {0.`, 0.5`}}, 
  "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}]}];

Show[m1["Wireframe"], 
 m1["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Red]]]
```

[image]

But now we collapse the element:

```
ToElementMesh[
 "Coordinates" -> {{0.`, 0.`}, {1.`, 0.`}, {1.`, 1.`}, {0.`, 
    1.`}, {0.5`, 0.`}, {1.`, 0.5`}, {0.5`, 1.`}, {0.`, 0.5`}}, 
 "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[{{1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 3, 8}}]}]

ToElementMesh::fememins: The mesh elements are not valid. A set of valid mesh element incidents needs to be positive integers and be able to form a complete sequence starting from 1 to the largest incident present. There are missing incidents; a complete sequence cannot be formed.

ToElementMesh::femtemnm: A mesh could not be generated.

$Failed
```

This approach will never work in an `ElementMesh`. You'd have to devise your own mesh structure for that.

I think you'd be better off explaining the stress computation at a crack tip and then we can see how to solve that.